# rvest::read_html() does not extract almost anything of the html code of this webpage

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to extract the hrefs from this page: [fincariz](https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/apartamentos-casas/venta/medellin?usado=true&pagina=1) but for some reason when I use:
`html_read <- rvest::read_html('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/apartamentos-casas/venta/medellin?usado=true&pagina=1')`
I get:

`[1]<head>\n<link rel="stylesheet" data-href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mulish:wght@400;500...`
`[2] <body>\n<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NHBHMXK" height="0"...`

For trying to extract the hrefs I use:

```
html_read %>%
      html_elements("div article a") %>%
      html_attr("href")
```

But I get no results and it seems that rvest did not extract the full html code that one's sees when inspecting the page with a web explorer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that the website is being generate with JavaScript, sou you'll probably need to use `rselenium`. Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652388/r-rvest-cant-get-html-node) would shed you some light.

Comment: @patL Indeed, with selenium I get the desired output with the html_code extracted. Was curious about the rvest only option. Thanks!